# facebook connect button for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am making iOS app using Facebook Connect. 
But I can't find "Facebook Connect button".
Where can I find "Facebook Connect button"? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have integrated facebook connect for web and you are searching for fb-connect-button.

I also searched for this thing in the past. You can't use FBML for ios. You will have to use 'rectangle buttone' and "fb-connect-button' image as its background. The tutorial that @F. X has recommended you has enough details on to how authentication and other major features can be implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had thought that "facebook connect button" distributed officially. However, it was found that there is a need to create their button. I'll create it using FBLoginView. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, "where's the Facebook Connect button in the XCode XIB editor?", then there's no Facebook Connect button in XCode. You have to use the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/) to do it.

*Side note: Search on Google, it's on the first page. Yeah, Google is your friend. Really.*

Comment: thank you for your answer. I checked "Facebook SDK". I can find "login-button-small" in FacebookSDKResources.bundle, it's too small.

Comment: Have you tried creating one yourself? Again, Google is your friend, but creating a custom `UIButton` with the size and image you want should be covered by most iOS books/tutorials, shoudn't it?

Comment: I was able to make login button using FBLoginView. It's thanks for your advice. Thanks.